# Tkinter Program for making a calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I am trying to make a simple GUI calculator just for addition/subtraction in the beginning. I am able to print the result to the console but I want to print it to the Entry box like the First Name entry box for example but not able to do it. I would really appreciate if you could help.(*Please neglect the alignment right now of the buttons I am focusing on the functioning, trying to get it right)

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox 
import sys
class scanner:
    list1 = []
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        self.entrytext1 = StringVar()
        Label(root, text="first name", width=10).grid(row=0,column=0)
        Entry(root, textvariable=self.entrytext, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(root, text="last name", width=10).grid(row=1,column=0)
        Entry(root, textvariable=self.entrytext1, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1)
        Button(root, text="ADD", command=self.add).grid()
        Button(root, text="SUBTRACT", command=self.subtract).grid()

    def add(self):
        global a
        global b
        self.a=int(self.entrytext.get())
        self.b=int(self.entrytext1.get())
        print "result is", self.a+self.b

    def subtract(self):
        global a
        global b
        self.a=int(self.entrytext.get())
        self.b=int(self.entrytext1.get())
        print "result is", self.a-self.b


root= Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
calc = scanner(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the result of the operation as a label's text, just create a new label and configure it with the `text` option and the string you are printing as its value. As a side note, you don't need the `global` statements, and the use of instance variables is not necessary either. However, it is very important to check that the content of the entries are actually valid numbers:

```
def __init__(self,parent):
    # ...
    self.result = Label(root, text='')
    self.result.grid(row=4, column=0)

def add(self):
    try:
        a = int(self.entrytext.get())
        b = int(self.entrytext1.get())
        self.result.config(text=str(a+b))
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect values")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add entry text to the widget, use the `insert` method. To replace the current text, you can call `delete` before you insert the new text.

```
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, "a default value")
```

The first parameter in the `delete` method is which number character to delete from and the second parameter is where to delete too. Notice how `END` is a tkinter variable.

The parameters for the `insert` function is where the text will be inserted too, and the second parameter is what will be inserted.

In the future, I recommend going to [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook) and reading about the widget that you are trying to use to find out all about it.